# Raspberrry Pi connecting to Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to firebase. I am very new to raspeberry pi. I installed firebase in the terminal using

```
sudo pip install python-firebase
```

Then i created a simple py file which only has the python

```
from firebase import firebase
```

When the file is ran i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/MYNAME/firebasetest.py", line 1, in <module>
from firebase import firebase
ImportError: No module named 'firebase'
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it myself, if anyone has same problem. I needed to download firebase for python 3 by using

```
sudo pip3 install python-firebase
```